# When a pushing enemy moves toward a character, does it stop moving on the first push?

Tags: dark-souls

If an enemy that pushes characters moves into his node but still has moves remaining, does it push the character away and then stop moving altogether, or does it continue to move forward?  Page 24 of the [rules](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56728f72a128e6b1e548ec55/t/58ebed0b15d5db2d9d8ac36c/1491856693806/DS-Core-Rules-lores.pdf) says:

> When an enemy model is moving towards another model, it will stop moving when it is on the same node as its target.

so, I gather that being on the same node triggers all moving to stop, or does the fact he pushes him away make him continue to move.  I would expect it to be the former as the target node is chosen at the beginning of movement, not updated each step.

Update: on page 25 it says

> is attack targets all characters on each node the enemy moves into. (Note that it does not target characters on the node on which the enemy started.) If an enemy moves 2 or more nodes, this can even result in the same character being attacked multiple times as the enemy tramples and smashes its way through its hapless victim.

So, does this mean if the enemy is 1 node away from its target but can move 2, it will aim to move only 1 space to the target's destination and then stop after it pushes the target away?

Are the hapless victims that get attacked multiple times only in extreme corner cases where the player cannot choose to have his character pushed to any node other than the one the enemy is trampling toward?  Otherwise I would expect they would simply choose a safe node since it is the player's choice where they get pushed to.

Further update:

On Page 30, a demonstration of boss movement clearly has the boss moving not *to* the initial position of the target (seems to pick the location after pushing, too). It moves toward and keep moving again after the character has been pushed back.  Unfortunately the player chooses to move the character directly away so we don't know if the boss would continue in that direction or turn and keep going toward the target if he had veered in the push.

and this [faq](http://forums.steamforged.com/index.php?/topic/37033-rules-faq-setup-activation-etc/) implies the boss picks the target character and for the entirety of its movement heads toward him, no matter how he gets pushed.  See the ENEMY MOVEMENT section under moving toward nearest or aggro and the looped section within.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at page 30, it looks like the movement resolves in the following order:

- If the movement contains a push, push everything in the current node
- Check direction towards movement objective
- Move to the corresponding node and push everything in that node
- Repeat

Granted, the rules don't really make that explicit, but they never contradict it either.

If you follow these steps, it is easy for a character to be trampled multiple times, since an enemy will **never be** in the same node as its target, since it will always be pushed away.

edit: after rereading page 21, I noticed it states:

> If the Push icon appears on an enemy’s movement, immediately
>   move each character on that enemy’s node onto an adjacent node
>   chosen by the players

Which indeed confirms the example on page 30.